# How to find the number of tuples that satisfy this property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

For integer $R>0$, denote by $$n(R)$$ and the number of triples
$$
(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}^3
$$
such that
$$
2x^2 + 3y^2 + 5z^2 = R.
$$

> What is the value of
> $$
> \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{n(1) + n(2) + \dots + n(R)}{R^{3/2}}?
> $$

I think that if you find the number of tuples that satisfy the equation for the values ​​of $R$, it is easy to solve the limit. I tried to make a conjecture for the function $n(R)$, my idea was to prove it by induction, but I couldn't. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Write $N(R) = n(1) + n(2) + \dots + n(R)$. It is very difficult to understand $n$ but much easier to understand $N$, at least approximately. $N(R)$ is the number of points $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ satisfying $2x^2 + 3y^2 + 5z^2 \le R$. The solutions to this inequality over $\mathbb{R}$ form an [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) with principal semi-axes of lengths $\sqrt{ \frac{R}{2} }, \sqrt{ \frac{R}{3} }, \sqrt{ \frac{R}{5} }$, hence with volume

$$V(R) = \frac{4\pi}{3} \sqrt{ \frac{R^3}{30} }.$$

Then $N(R)$ counts the number of lattice points inside this ellipsoid. It's not hard to convince yourself that for large $R$ this is approximately the volume; more precisely we should have $N(R) = V(R) + O(R)$, where the error is proportional to the surface area, and you could write down more precise upper and lower bounds along these lines if you wanted to be careful. We should be able to prove $V(R) - C_1 R \le N(R) \le V(R) + C_2 R$ for explicit constants $C_1, C_2$.

So the value of the desired limit is $\boxed{ \frac{4 \pi}{3 \sqrt{30}} }$.